# Is it possible to have a comment in files that tells VSCode how to run a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to have a comment in a file that allows you to customize exactly how VSCode will run that file? Vaguely similar to a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

For example, when editing a specific yaml file as part of an ansible playbook, I would like to be able to press a button and execute the parent playbook in ansible with the tag relevant for executing only the tasks in that file.

Comment: search/write an extension that parses your special comment and start the correct task, or place the command in the settings of the extension and differentiate on file path

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a *modeline*; if you put this at the beginning of the file, VSCode will pick up the Ansible association:

`# code: language=ansible`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.ansible